# Slow wp_enqueue_media()

Tags: query, media

I have developed a WordPress plugin for my site that utilises the WP Media uploader to store files... To do this my plugin contains the following code:

```
function enqueue_scripts()
{
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
  wp_enqueue_media();
  // etc...
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts');
```

I noticed the admin area was becoming really slow so I ran some query logs and it appears the query triggered by wp_enqueue_media();

```
SELECT ID 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE post_type = 'attachment' 
AND post_mime_type LIKE 'audio%' 
LIMIT 1
```

After a quick Google search I can see it is a known problem on large sites that was apparently fixed many versions previous.... obviously not!

I'm not quite sure how to proceed? I need this functionality in my plugin. I am a little confused why this function needs calling when it appears to generally be available throughout the admin area.. Even stranger, when i'm loading things from my enqueue_scripts() function they are being made available globally, which I'm assuming is what is happening to wp_enqueue_media() as it is slowing the whole admin area and not just the plugin.

I presumed it would only load resources when it needed them.

Is there a way around it? or is there a way to only trigger enqueue_scripts() when I am using the plugin?

I just don't get why I need to load these from the plugin, but then it's made globally to all other plugins.

Comment: admin_enqueue_scripts provides you with an $hook for your function. by this $hook you can execute this enqueue only for your pages in the admin. so it does not slow down everything. this as a first tipp. https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To load admin scripts only on your pages, you should use the `$hook`-parameter:

```
function enqueue_scripts( $hook )
{
  if( 'my-page' != $hook )
    return;

  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
  wp_enqueue_media();
  // etc...
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts');
```

Concerning the loading problem. This seems to be still an open problem. The [ticket 27985](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/27985) was followed up by [#32264](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/32264), which is not closed yet. The last edit on this was 24hours ago :)

Seems like they are searching for a solution and will implement it soon :)

Comment: This work around appears to have worked thanks... hopefully they fix it soon. Plugins should definitely be sandboxed in my opinion.

Comment: If you don't know the hook of your plugin page (it is different to the page slug), then you can use the [`get_plugin_page_hook()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_plugin_page_hook/) function.